# Check entire column for values greather than x and return cells

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table like this:

```
Values
1000
1000
3000
2000
4000
```

I need to check the entire column for values bigger than a given one (for example 3000) and return all cells where the condition is True.

Comment: What do you mean by "return all cells"?  What should the output look like?

Comment: Any output that helps me to find cells where the value is greater than the given one.  Now I have a second column where is printed TRUE or FALSE. Is there a way to, for example, to print in a new page only rows where the formula gives TRUE?

Comment: Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With data in column **A**, run this short macro:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim N As Long, K As Long, i As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    K = 1
    For i = 2 To N
        If Cells(i, "A").Value > 3000 Then
            Cells(K, 2).Value = Cells(i, "A").Address(0, 0)
            Cells(K, 3).Value = Cells(i, "A").Value
            K = K + 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

To produce a listing of which cells exceed *3000* and their value:

[image]

and if you only need the values, you could use AutoFilter:

[image]